# Why react native can find correct locations of .js files to be imported?

Tags: react-native, import

Just beginning to learn react native, I am trying to figure out how react native projects are run but am confused at the following code:

```
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
```

I assumed that there should be files like Text.js and TextInput.js in my project folders that will be invoked in the execution. I did find both but they are in different locations. Text.js is in proj_root\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Text but TextInput.js is in proj_root\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\TextInput. Since they are in different levels of the directory hierarchy, how can the React Native's execution environment correctly find them? From the 'import' instruction I used, I feel confused.

Much appreciated for any help. If there is useful information (books or webpages) to realize how RN projects are run with correct settings, please kindly share. Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This all relates to how exports are handled in node js environments: simplified, “react-native” points to “[your project’s root]/node_modules/react-native”, and inside that folder (and, in fact, all node_modules packages) you will find a `package.json` which contains a key `“main” : “some-js-file.js”`.

I have not checked “react-native” specifically, but generally this “main” key value is “index.js” which would point to `node_modules/react-native/index.js`. In this `index.js` file `AppRegistry` `View` etc. are exported.

Of course, in the index.js, they are usually imported first using `require` before being re-exported.

Webpack is pretty handy at handling a lot of these exports and compiling them into production vs dev versions, but the whole idea begins with `node_modules` folders and `package.json` files, which points to an index.js. This index.js would usually serve your project the components you asked for above depending on environment, e.g if you are developing it will hand you a Dev version of that component with propTypes that log wanted errors at runtime, or if you building for production it will hand you a Prod version of the component with performance benefits, etc.

Webpack can bundle your code to create such libraries as the ones you see in `node_modules` folder (such as react-native), and there diferent ways of exporting (e.g. commonjs, amd, umd, global var) but that is really beyond the scope of this question and something to consider if you want to create your own “node_module”.